# Upgrade Windows Azure web role to Server 2008 R2 to use IIS 7.5

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I just launched my test website in Windows Azure this weekend with a single web role.  I didn't see any options to specify what OS to use.  It is currently using Server 2008 (IIS 7).  According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/11/29/just-released-windows-azure-sdk-1-3-and-the-new-windows-azure-management-portal.aspx) though, Server 2008 R2 web roles are available (IIS 7.5).  I want to use some specific functionality of IIS 7.5 - **how can I upgrade my web role to use Server 2008 R2?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just specify `osFamily="2"` in `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg`.

Comment: The portal also offers the ability to upgrade w/o repushing the deployment, but typically you'd want to repush anyways

Comment: Thanks smarx. Hard to find that searching but that works. And Taylor, you are right also but when I was in the portal earlier the option to configure O/S was disabled.